# Cuenta atras js

Tags: javascript, async-await

estoy tratando de hacer una cuenta atras con async que pille los parametros que le indico.
Pero no me esta funcionando correctamente, soy nuevo en esto del js que error podría estar realizando ?

```js
export async function interval(id, i,intervalo) {
  var counter = id;
  var id = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
      interval(60, 1);
    } else {
      counter = counter - i;
      document.body.innerHTML = counter;
    }
  }, intervalo);
}

interval(60,1,1000);
```

Se esperaria que saliera una cuenta atras en pantalla desde el 60 hasta el 0.

> 60,59,58,57,56,etc.

Lo que yo he tratado de hacer es pasar los parametros a la funcion y a partir de ahi crear la cuenta hacia atras, lo que pasa es que no termino de entender muy creo el funcionamiento de las funciones async siempre deben funcionar con una promesa? o pueden funcionar con calquier variable que haga cualquier cosa? En este caso no he creado ninguna promesa ya que pensaba que funcionaban sin, si alguien me pueda aclarar?? Creo que no entiendo muy bien todo este tipo de funciones. Tampoco se si las puedo exportar, se que por ejemplo si elimino export si funciona correctamente. Pero necesito exportarla desde un fichero externo a un html, esto como se haria? Gracias!

Comment: Hay varias cosas que no esn bien y algunas que no se entiende, puedes indicar por ejemplo, cual seria la salida esperada de la ejecucion. Por ejemplo, usa `document.body` ya que `document.getAttribute()` no es valido. Revisa la consola de JS y veras algunos errores que te daran mas pistas.

Comment: vale ahora edito la pregunta con lo que estoy esperando como salida del programa

Answer (score 1):

Esto te puede servir mucho:

```js
var r = 60;
var l = document.getElementById("n");
window.setInterval(function(){
  l.innerHTML = r;
  r--;
},1000);
```

```html
<div id="n"></div>
```